# Calling a Java Method using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, methods, process, multiprocessing, processbuilder

Is there any way to call a Java method using the ProcessBuilder API?

I wish to execute a Java method using processes only for some reason. Thus, I have written this code so  far -

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "--version");
Process proc = p.start();
```

I know that this would print the current java version on my laptop. I wish to call a Java Method for example, Class1.doAddition() instead of printing the Java version.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Write a class with a `main` method that calls that method. Compile everything and build a `java` launch command that use that class as its entry point.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the _results_ of `doAddition()`? This sounds like the wrong way to do what you're trying to do for many reasons.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, I'll do as you suggested.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I just wish to call a function instead of a program. Whats wrong in this?

Comment: Nothing, but why are you trying to use a mechanism designed to run a program to cal a method?